# wso2 esb axis2_nhttp.xml

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, nio, esb

In WSO2 ESB we have 2 axis2 xml files axis2.xml and axis2_nhttp.xml.
In a scenario where the wso2 service  need to call an rest endpoints , the interface is working only when we use axis2_nhttp.xml and not working when using axis2.xml.

Can anyone let us know what the difference is and if there are any drawbacks if we use axis2_nhttp.xml ? we need to have ssl and also security handlers implemented for our  wso2 services

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [WSO2 Docs:](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Tuning+the+HTTP+Transport)

> WSO2 ESB supports two non-blocking transports, namely the [passthrough](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP+PassThrough+Transport)
>   transport and the [nhttp](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP-NIO+Transport) transport. The passthrough transport is the
>   default transport of the ESB, but you can set the NHTTP transport as
>   the default transport by renaming the
>   /repository/conf/axis2/axis2_nhttp.xml file to axis2.xml.

You can read more about ESB transports [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configuring+Transports).

So when you replace `axis2.xml` by `axis2_nhttp.xml`, you enabled NHTTP trasport (and disabled default passthrough transport). However, the important thing to note here is that REST endpoint calls should work in either transport. So there must be some issues in your synapse configuration.

Comment: I agree the basic behaviour should not change ,  We tried with call (with non-blocking true) and also with send none is working with the default axis2 xml but the moment we change the axix2_nhttp to axis2 it is working as expected wondering where the problem might be.

Comment: Can you post your synapse config?

Comment: not able to post the code here its too long , can I attach it somewhere ?

Comment: Code - http://pastebin.com/UfZ46z6H
Error - http://pastebin.com/tWCA6jtN

Comment: pls let me know if yu are not able to access

Comment: This error usually happens when the `charset` is not available in request/response in `Content-Type` header. eg. `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` Please check your requests and responses.

Comment: we had tried with the charset and the content-Type as well , but no luck